# unable to update values in ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I am trying to save the values from a ListFragment as they are clicked in a HashMap and trying to access them on a button click but hashmap is always empty. 
Inside my toggle values function I can see the hash map getting updated but when I access it on button click listener it comes as empty.
Is there anything I am missing about the fragments?

```
public class SListFragment extends ListFragment {
private Button button;
private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
View rootView;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    adapter = new listAdapter(
            getActivity().getApplication(), list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {      
    toggleValues(position);
}

@Override
public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
    return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    cButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_contribute);
    cButtonOnClickListener();
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

private void cButtonOnClickListener(){


    cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cButton.setText("ok");
            Intent cIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), CActivity.class);                
            cIntent.putExtra("position", hmap);
            //here hmap is empty; I don't understand  why?

            startActivity(cIntent);
        }
    });
}

private void toggleValues(int position){

    if(hmap.containsKey(position)){
        hmap.remove(position);
    }
    else {
        hmap.put(position,"position");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think the problem is in button initialization.  Yor are initializing it directly but instead you have to use rootView to initialize th you ahve to use findViewByid();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a demo using your post. The bug not appears:

```java
public class SListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private Button cButton;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");
        list.add("four");
        list.add("five");
        list.add("six");
        list.add("seven");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        toggleValues(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_text_demo, container, false);
        cButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_contribute);
        cButtonOnClickListener();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void cButtonOnClickListener() {

        cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cButton.setText("ok");
                Intent cIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                cIntent.putExtra("position", hmap);
                Set<Entry<Integer, String>> sets = hmap.entrySet();
                Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> it = sets.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();
                    Log.d("demo", "hmap key: " + entry.getKey() + " --> value: " + entry.getValue());
                }

                // here hmap is empty; I don't understand why?

                // startActivity(cIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleValues(int position) {

        if (hmap.containsKey(position)) {
            hmap.remove(position);
        }
        else {
            hmap.put(position, "position");
        }
    }
}
```

This is layout file `activity_text_demo` used by the fragment:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_contribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Button" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this works but why do I have to create a list view in xml file when list fragment already has a list view in it. Initially my button btn_contribute was in xml file for activity and I was calling it in fragment. When I made a separate xml file for fragment  and put my list view and button in it  and inflated it in fragment just as you have done it works fine. I don't understand this behavior.  Can you explain

Comment: Yes, you need not to create a list view in xml file for the list fragment. The fragment providers a default content view contained a list view. I rewrite my codes, but it still be OK. I post the all code as a new answer. It be just for your information. Hope help you.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the test codes. I put a button in the `MainActivity`'s xml file and use the default list view contained in the list fragment:

`MainActivity.java`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (findViewById(R.id.content_container) != null && savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_container, new SListFragment()).commit();

        }
    }

}
```

and this is the activity's xml file `activity_main.xml`:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn_contribute"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Button" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the list fragment `SListFragment.java`. Actually it is familiar to the codes post by @peaceofmind:

```java
public class SListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {
    private Button cButton;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    View rootView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list.add("one");
        list.add("two");
        list.add("three");
        list.add("four");
        list.add("five");
        list.add("six");
        list.add("seven");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                list);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        toggleValues(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        cButton = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_contribute);
        cButtonOnClickListener();

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void cButtonOnClickListener() {

        cButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cButton.setText("ok");
                Intent cIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplication(), MainActivity.class);
                cIntent.putExtra("position", hmap);
                Set<Entry<Integer, String>> sets = hmap.entrySet();
                Iterator<Entry<Integer, String>> it = sets.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();
                    Log.d("demo", "hmap key: " + entry.getKey() + " --> value: " + entry.getValue());
                }

                // here hmap is empty; I don't understand why?

                // startActivity(cIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void toggleValues(int position) {

        if (hmap.containsKey(position)) {
            hmap.remove(position);
        }
        else {
            hmap.put(position, "position");
        }
    }
}
```